# Guzzle hangs Apache when passing PHPSESSID session cookie

Tags: php, apache, session, session-cookies, guzzle

I am using Guzzle get request in one PHP script to fetch another.

```
$guzzle->get("urltomysecondpage")->getBody();
```

However, Guzzle is not aware of the session ID cookie, so my target script cannot access session variables.

Documentation states that all I have to do is set "cookies" to "true" and Guzzle shall use the same cookie set that the calling script sees.

```
$guzzle->get("urltomysecondpage", ['cookies' => TRUE])->getBody();
```

However, this simply doesn't work. The target script sees no cookies. Documentation also allows to explicitly set an array of cookies like this:

```
$guzzle->get("urltomysecondpage", ['cookies' => ['PHPSESSID'=>$_COOKIE['PHPSESSID']]])->getBody();
```

It works, but not if I specify one of the cookies to have the key "PHPSESSID". If I do, the Apache server hangs completely. Not only the current request, but it also stops responding to all requests.

What's going on?

Comment: Check your error logs.

Comment: Any luck fixing this? I'm having the same problem and can't get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

The webserver isn't able to open the same session for 2 requests. To fix this you can first close the session and then reopen it after you've made the request with Guzzle.

Example:

```
session_start();

$sessionId = session_id();

session_write_close();

$client = new Client(
    array(
        'base_uri' => 'http://www.yoursite.tld',
        'cookies' => false,
    )
);

$cookie = new GuzzleHttp\Cookie\SetCookie();
$cookie->setName('PHPSESSID');
$cookie->setValue($sessionId);
$cookie->setDomain('www.yoursite.tld');

$cookieJar = new CookieJar(
    false,
    array(
        $cookie,
    )
);

$response = $client->request(
    'GET',
    '/urltomysecondpage',
    array(
        'cookies' => $cookieJar,
    )
);

session_start();
```

Answer (score 0):

I had some trouble using the `cookies => true` option. have you tried providing a default `CooieJar`?

Example:

```
$jar = new GuzzleHttp\Cookie\CookieJar();
$default = [
    "cookies" => $jar
];
$c = new GuzzleHttp\Client(["defaults" => $default]);
```

The same cookie jar is now set by default to each request made by that client.

Comment: The docs cover this but as far as I can tell it doesn't work: http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#cookies